# PrintWriter vs BufferedWriter

Tags: java, sockets, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to transfer strings from my server to my client and I'm trying to find an explanation why when I'm using `PrintWriter` in my server the client receives the string while when I'm using `BufferedWriter` the client doesn't receive the string.

In my client I have the next readers/writers:

```
out=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
```

In my main I'm receiving data from server with the next call:

```
String sol=in.readLine();
```

In my server I'm sending data with the next call (os is an outputStream that I get in my function):

```
PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(os);
out.write("test");
out.flush();
```

While when I use `BufferedWriter` it doesn't send data to the client (or the client can't receive it?) "

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
out.append("test"); // tried also using out.write
out.flush();
```

Comment: For the buffered writer you must use write method as well as for print writer

Comment: Tried the writer also, same result

Comment: Hard to tell from your code snippet, but your reader is expecting a "line", so I assume your print writer might be adding a carriage return to the data being sent, whereas the buffer is not. However, that cannot be asserted from your code. Worth a try though!

Comment: Because you used `PrintWriter.println()`, which sends a line terminator, but `BufferedWriter.write()`, which doesn't, and you are using `readLine()`, which blocks until the line terminator is received, or end-of-stream or an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

On my server side Bufferwriter doesn't add "\n" to the end of the string while in my client side I'm trying to read a line with inputstream. Printwriter adds "\n" in the method println. Thanks to @EdwinDalorzo for the help.